# PDF viewing app on Iphone. Options?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, flash, pdf

Is there such a thing as a brandable Iphone app that views PDF's?

Alternatively is it possible to view PDF's via a Flash app, or via something such as PhoneGap? as this is were my skills are, I dont know any Objective C.

Comment: Sorry, it was a joke - that Apple adamantly opposes Flash on iPhone/iOS is a widely-reported business conflict over the past couple years

Comment: iPhones can view PDF's directly, no need for any additional software

Comment: true that, but they changed there minds and do allow apps using the iphone packager in CS5.

Comment: http://www.allthingsandroid.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/AVI.jpg

Comment: @hunter - can they be embedded in html though?

Comment: The emphasis here is on the _brandable_ right?

Comment: @davivid - I'm not sure but I can't imagine creating a decent UI for a PDF within a page on a screen that size. Might be best to detect the iPhone and allow it to be opened independently.

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView supports displaying a PDF.

There is no directory area where you can just double tap a PDF and view it due to iPhone design. As such there is no app like PDF Reader which just views PDFs.

However you can either use the web browser and navigate to a PDF or email it to yourself and view the attachment.